# How can I filter a SQL query using the MAX of a column without subqueries?

Tags: mysql, subquery, max, aggregate-functions

I have a query that works something like this (MySQL):

Query:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d FROM xTable WHERE d=(
    SELECT MAX(d) FROM xTable WHERE uid=1
) AND c=0
```

Sample:

```
--xTable--
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  | uid |
| 30  | str | 20  | 32  | 1   |
| 36  | abc | 0   | 32  | 1   |
| 20  | ... | 40  | 33  | 1   |
| 19  | dsi | 0   | 34  | 1   |
| 68  |aeasd| 0   | 34  | 1   |
| 112 |3eids| 224 | 34  | 1   |
```

I want only the rows with the biggest d (34) and uid=X, but only the ones with c=0.

Is there a way to replicate this query without subqueries?

Comment: What is wrong with the subquery?

Comment: I'm going to apply the query in a huge database that's going to have many inserts happening maybe at the same time and there are some people saying that the subqueries can cause a race condition in these kind of applications and I should avoid them. I'm not sure about that, but better safe than sorry. So, I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: Without proper DDLs and a desired result set I can't quite grasp what you're after, but maybe you should instead be looking at transactions.

Answer (score 0):

It can be rewritten into a JOIN but I don't see why that would improve anything (although with MySQL's limited query optimizer you never know...)

```
SELECT t1.a, 
       t1.b, 
       t1.c, 
       t1.d 
FROM xTable t1
  JOIN (
     SELECT MAX(d) as max_d
     FROM xTable 
     WHERE uid=1
  ) t2 ON t2.max_d = t1.d
WHERE t1.c=0
```

Comment: @Macmod: it's not a subquery, it's a derived table.

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know if this will help you but since your worry is regarding changing database due to frequent inserts, you can try the solution below which will remove the dynamism of getting the max by selecting the max beforehand and using that as the comparison. It will get the row with the max you have at the point you choose to fire the query.

`with m as (select max(d) as d from xTable ) select a, b, c, d  from xTable where d = (select d from m) ;`

So here, you have your max fixed for the current query.